# Rotate elements of matrix in counter clockwise direction

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, rotation

How can we rotate `5X5` matrix in conuter clock wise direction by `45` degree?

Input will be like this:

```
00100
00100
11111
00100
00100
```

And output should be like this:

```
10001
01010
00100
01010
10001
```

What I have done so far is I have read elements of `5X5` array now I have stuck with the logic of rotation.

My code is as below:

```java
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RotateMatrix {
  public static void main(String a[]) {
    int[][] original = new int[5][5];
    int[][] rotate = new int[5][5];
    String helper[] = new String[5];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      helper[i] = sc.next();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        original[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(helper[i].charAt(j)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this rotation by hand? What happens to the elements in the 2x2 corners?

Comment: Matrix size is fixed.It will be always 5X5 matrix.I need logic or any formula to implement it in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "rotating by 45 degrees" means that entries on the outer border should stay on the outer border, what you need to do is:

- rotate the outer 5x5 ring by 2 positions
- rotate the inner 3x3 ring by 1 position

The outer 5x5 ring rotates like this:

```
01234      23456
F   5      1   7
E   6  =>  0   8
D   7      F   9
CBA98      EDCBA
```

You can do this rotation with a for loop. This one does top, right and bottom sides as an example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i < 3) {
    rotate[0][i] = original[0][i+2]; // TOP
    rotate[i][4] = original[i+2][4]; // RIGHT
    rotate[4][4-i] = original[4][4-(i+2)]; // BOTTOM
  } else {
    rotate[0][i] = original[i-2][4]; // TOP
    rotate[i][4] = original[4][4-(i-2)]; // RIGHT
    rotate[4][4-i] = original[4-(i-2)][0]; // BOTTOM
  }
}
```

Once you add the code to fill the left side of `rotate` and the code to rotate the inner 3x3 ring you're done!

This may amount to quite a lot of code. You may want to make a method that rotates an arbitrary ring of the matrix by 1. Then you would call this method 3 times: once on the inner ring, and twice on the outer ring so it rotates by 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Your code helped me a lot..Rest of the code I have completed..!!